# Use Raspberry Pi libraries when crosscompiling from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am making a program for my Raspberry Pi using Visual Studio 2017 for windows.
I am currently crosscompiling everthing and it works great. But now i need to include a library that is found on the Raspberry Pi that Visual Studio won't find.

In the code i am using `#include "/usr/include/mosquitto.h` but Visual Studio can't find it. Is there a way to let Visual Studio know that the file exists? And make sure it can compile it?

Comment: Are you cross compiling or remote compiling? Please post the error output from the build window.

Comment: I think i found it. I used [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) tutorial to guide me through the setup process. But i was stupid. further down the tutorial there is a description in how to use the includes from yoru raspberry pi.